# Python list to list of lists

Tags: python, list

Is there an easy way to convert a list of doubles into a list of lists of doubles?

For example:

```
[1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
```

into

```
[[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]]
```

The code I'm using requires the second as inputs to a bunch of functions but it's annoying to have two copies of the same data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just use a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) wrapping each element in a list:

```
l = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
print [[x] for x in l]
[[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]]
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to list comprehensions, you could try `map`:

```
>>> map(lambda x: [x], l)
[[1.0], [2.0], [3.0]]
```

This gives the desired result by applying the `lambda` function (here, taking an object and putting it in a list) to each element of `l` in turn.

In Python 3 `map` returns an iterator so use `list(map(lambda x: [x], l))` to get the list.

---

Using `map` is about twice as slow as list comprehension for small lists of `floats` because building the `lambda` function incurs a small overhead:

```
>>> %timeit [[x] for x in l]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 594 ns per loop

>>> %timeit map(lambda x: [x], l)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.25 us per loop
```

For longer lists, the time gap between the two starts to close, although list comprehension remains the [preferred option in the Python community](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1247490/3923281).

Comment: *Interestingly*? It seems quite obvious as to why .. Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map BTW, I like `map` more ;)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - I'd intended the word *interestingly* to mean "worth noting" rather than "mysteriously"... I'll update my answer with a better choice of word and explain the reason why :-)

Comment: If you find out a way not to use `lambda` here, then `map` will be faster!

Answer (score 0):

It may not be necessary, but if list-comprehensions are cryptic, here's a general solution using a for-loop:

```
def convert(l):
    converted = []
    if isinstance(l, list):
        if len(l) > 0:
            for n in l:
                converted.append([n])
    return converted

l = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
print convert(l)
```

You could also check wether each element in the list is a float or not, and raise an error if one of them isn't:

```
class NotFloatError(Exception):

    def __init__(self, message):
        Exception.__init__(self, message)

def convert(l):
    converted = []
    if isinstance(l, list):
        if len(l) > 0:
            for n in l:
                if isinstance(n, float):
                    converted.append([n])
                else:
                    raise NotFloatError("An element in the list is not a float.")
    return converted

l = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
print convert(l)
```

Comment: I'd say this is more cryptic than the list comprehension by a mile.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
for x in a:
    a = [x]
    print a
```